# regex help for typo correction

Tags: php, regex

I have hundreds of document where one word is spelt in all crazy ways possible. So, would like to correct that through regex search and repalce - php.

Here is the real sample (incomplete):

```
J U D G M E T
J U D E M E N T
JUDGEMENT
J U D G M F N T
J U D G NE N T
J U D G N E N T  
J U D G M E N FT
J U D G M E T
J U N C M E N T
J U D G M E F T
J U G M E N T
J U D G E M E N T
J U D E M E N T
J U D G R E N T
J U D G E N T
J U E G M E N T
J U D G M E M T
J u d g m e n t
JUDGMEAT
JUGMENT
```

The correct word is JUDGMENT
The above list is incomplete and there could be various typos and not possible to check all the documents. There could be space or no space between two letters in the actual document and letters can be lower or upper case mixed except for the first letter J.

Basically, JU is common and rest has been misspelled.
What should be the regex pattern match so that every bit (or majority of them if not all) can be fixed.

Would the following be OK for 8 letter typo and we do same for 7 and 9 letter ones?

```
'/J\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}\s?/'
```

We will do only 1 replacement per document.

TIA

Comment: does anything else start with "JU" or "J U"?

Comment: Do you always have 1 word per line? In the given example do you want to replace the 20 lines by the correct word `JUDGMENT`?

How many different words do you have?  If you have many I suggest that you create a list of correct words spelling to check against with pregmatch.
Do you want to leave only one occurence of the correct spelling in each file?

Comment: @Dagon
Yes, I want only one correction per file.
Words that can start with J U/JU/Ju are:

Judge
Judges
Judgment date
Judgement date but, they won't be replaced as I would be replacing only the start of a part of the document.

Comment: @antoni

The 20 lines are from 20 files checked randomly. 
Each file only has one typo and that's in the heading/subheading of the document. So, only one replacement is needed.

I have split the whole document into two parts through identifiers and it's the beginning of the second part where this typo happens. So, by limiting it to 1 replace per file, I am not risking changing other parts.

Comment: (1) All your examples end with `T`, can we use that? (2) If there's space between letters, is it exactly one space character?  Not tabs or anything else? (3) Will the next non-whitespace character after the word be on the same line?  Will it be a letter, punctuation, or unknown?

Comment: @AlanMoore - 
(1) Nice point. Yes all end in T (T|t). 

(2) The space is only restricted to single space. No tabs etc. But in the same word the space between two letter may or may not be there. So spacing is also to be considered as random -- but single space only.

(3) Can be a blank space, no blank space. The word is on the same line so no line breaks within the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of a regular expression and a `PHP` function called `levenshtein()`.

#### Idea

First, the [regex selects a "word"](https://regex101.com/r/jN5eX9/1) (*starting with "J" and ending with "T"*) and then uses [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to hook into the replacements.
If the [`levenshtein()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance is below 5 (or whatever you set it to) it is considered similar.

#### Code

```
<?php

$string = "J U D G M E T  J U D E M E N T  JUDGEMENT  J U D G M F N T  J U D G NE N T  J U D G N E N T  
J U D G M E N FT  J U D G M E T  J U N C M E N T  J U D G M E F T  J U G M E N T  J U D G E M E N T  
J U D E M E N T  J U D G R E N T  J U D G E N T  J U E G M E N T  J U D G M E M T  J u d g m e n T  JUDGMEAT  JUGMENT JUT";

$regex = '~\bJ\h?(?:[a-z]\h?)+T\b~i';

$word = "JUDGEMENT";

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($match) use ($word) {
        $word2 = strtoupper(str_replace(' ', '', $match[0]));

        if (levenshtein($word, $word2) <= 2)
            return $word;
        else
            return $match[0]; // leave it

    },
    $string);

echo $string;
?>
```

This replaces all of the above except `J U N C M E N T` and `JUT`  (considered too far away).

#### Demo

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/PrfcgV) for the whole code.
Thanks to @Alan for the `strtoupper()` hint.

Comment: You might as well call `strtoupper()` on the matched word before you Levenshtein it.

Answer (score 1):

Working with PHP and let's assume - if I understand well - that you have multiple files with one word attempt per line.

I am sure there are plenty of solutions, but here are the 2 I come up with.

FIRST SOLUTION - if you want to completely guess with no correct word list:

1 - I would first remove all `\s+` giving

```
JUDGMET
JUDEMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDGMFNT
JUDGNENT
JUDGNENT
JUDGMENFT
JUDGMET
JUNCMENT
JUDGMEFT
JUGMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDEMENT
JUDGRENT
JUDGENT
JUEGMENT
JUDGMEMT
Judgment
JUDGMEAT
JUGMENT
```

2 - strtoupper() everything, giving:

```
JUDGMET
JUDEMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDGMFNT
JUDGNENT
JUDGNENT
JUDGMENFT
JUDGMET
JUNCMENT
JUDGMEFT
JUGMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDEMENT
JUDGRENT
JUDGENT
JUEGMENT
JUDGMEMT
JUDGMENT
JUDGMEAT
JUGMENT
```

3 - foreach letter, find the mostly used and save it in an array. You will then create the array containing the letters in correct order.
it will get as close as possible of the correct spelling but still need human check.

4 - then replace file content with your word.

---

SECOND SOLUTION if you assume you have a list of words to check:

1 - do the first 2 steps of previous solution,

2 - foreach new line word compare with the list of correct words,

3 - in loop, if matching, break the loop and keep this correct word

4 - replace file content with correct word

hope this is what you need! :)

[EDIT] AFTER COMMENTS TO REFINE THE QUESTION:

So I was misleaded, but wanted to share my solution code anyway as I think it is very interesting in terms of data mining and quite helpful! :)
So here I was assuming we want the first solution case.

```
<?php
$string =
"JUDGMET
JUDEMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDGMFNT
JUDGNENT
JUDGNENT
JUDGMENFT
JUDGMET
JUNCMENT
JUDGMEFT
JUGMENT
JUDGEMENT
JUDEMENT
JUDGRENT
JUDGENT
JUEGMENT
JUDGMEMT
JUDGMENT
JUDGMEAT
JUGMENT";

$words = explode("\n", $string);
$letters = [];
$longestWord = '';

foreach ($words as $word) if (strlen($word) >= strlen($longestWord)) $longestWord = $word;

for ($i = 0; $i <= strlen($longestWord); $i++)
{
    foreach ($words as $wordCheck)
    {
        $letter = !isset($wordCheck{$i}) ? '' : $wordCheck{$i};
        if (!isset($lettersAtPosition[$i][$letter])) $lettersAtPosition[$i][$letter] = 0;
        $lettersAtPosition[$i][$letter]++;

        if ($lettersAtPosition[$i] == '') break;
        $flippedArray = array_flip($lettersAtPosition[$i]);
        krsort($flippedArray);
        $letters[$i] = array_shift($flippedArray);
    }
}

echo implode('', $letters);
?>
```

will output `JUDGMENT`

Comment: There's only one replacement and not across the file for each line. I kept the s? because the spaces are random between the letters.

Answer (score 0):

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT4jX2/1)

```
[Jj] ?[Uu](?: ?\w)+
```

may try this regex

Comment: I think checking the first 2 letters is not enough. you may have other files with other words. also you assume that we already know the correct word.